# How to load rows after a specific id and track newer rows using Kafka JDBC Connector?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, connector, apache-kafka-connect

I am using [Kafka JDBC Connecter](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc) to import data from MySQL database into Kafka topic. With the parameters below, I am able to track newer rows inserted into the given table.

```
name=test
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=10

connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=asdf
table.whitelist=test_table

mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id

topic.prefix=test-
```

What I need is to load all records after a specific id from the table and also track all new inserted records. How can I achieve that? One solution might be to have a custom query with a filtering, but I am not sure about a query.

Answer (score 0):

Custom query should probably be "select * from table where id > X"
X being the specific id you mentioned.

Comment: Just note that if you go this route, you probably can't use incremental mode: http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.2/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html#incremental-query-modes

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.2/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html#incremental-query-modes) says that _Alternatively, the specified query may handle filtering to new updates itself; however, note that no offset tracking will be performed so the query must track offsets itself._ 

Then, How could we do offset tracking in the query itself?

Answer (score 0):

Well i haven't done this before. But i still think it is doable which obviously will need some code change. In JdbcSourceTask.start method, offsets are loaded using below code.

```
offsets = context.offsetStorageReader().offsets(partitions);
```

Here you can define your own offset. However, there is one issue. This offset will be loaded everytime you restart your connector instead of the one which is saved in the topic. Further, to resolve this, you can define a custom configuration like below.

```
 connector.firsttime=true
```

Then same can be utilized in the start method as below:

```
String strIsFirstTime
    = config.getString(JdbcSourceTaskConfig.FIRST_TIME_CONFIG);
if("true".equals(strIsFirstTime)){
//load custom offset
//lStartingPosition is the value at which you want to start the processing.
Long lStartingPosition=Long.MAX_VALUE;
//partition is the relevant partiton of the table in question.
  offsets.put(partition, new TimestampIncrementingOffset(null,lStartingPosition).toMap()); 
}
else{
offsets = context.offsetStorageReader().offsets(partitions);
}
```

However, remember to set this custom configuration to false whenever, this connector is restarted.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to have it done is by creating a view for your custom query and have a filter in the predicate.

```
create or replace view xyz as select * from table where id > X;


name=test
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=10

connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=asdf
table.whitelist=test_table

mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id

topic.prefix=test-

poll.interval.ms : 300000,
query: "select id from xyz"
```